# Unable to get child model details using parent model in laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel-4

Hi guys i was trying laravel model relations. But I am unable to get parent model details using child model.

I have a parent table `'category' ('id', 'name', 'created_at', 'updated_at')` and child table `'subcategory' ('id', 'cid', 'name', 'created_at', 'updated_at')`.  Here are the models I have:

Category model:

```
class Cat extends Eloquent
{
protected $table="category";
public function Subcat()
{
    return $this->hasMany('CatSub', 'cid', 'id');
}   
}
```

Sub category model:

```
class CatSub extends Eloquent
{
protected $table="subcategory";
public function cat()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Cat', 'cid', 'id');
}
}
```

When I try to get details of parent model using child model, its working perfectly

```
 $subcat=CatSub::all();

 foreach($subcat as $subcat):
 echo $subcat->cat->name;// displays list of parent categories
 endforeach;
```

But when I try to access child model details using parent model its not working.

And its showing error '**Undefined property $name**'.

Here is the code:

```
 $cat=Cat::all();
 foreach($cat as $cat):
 echo $cat->subcat->name;
 endforeach;
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Eloquent doesn't throw undefined property error, it's uses `__get` and returns `null` if attribute/relation/property is not found. You don't have Eloquent model there.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The parent model 'category' **haMany**  'subcategory' so have to use another foreach inside existing foreach to get subcategory details.

```
 $cat=Cat::all();
 foreach($cat as $cat):
 $tmp=$cat->subcat;
 foreach($tmp as $subcat):
 echo $subcat->name;
 endforeach;
 endforeach;
```